# Zariski closure of a set using the topological definition of closure

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

I am aware of the more standard proof that for $Z \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n(k)$, $\overline Z = V\left(I(Z)\right)$, its closure in the Zariski topology. I was wondering if this result could also be had using the [definition of closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)#Closure_of_a_set) in general topology as the intersection of all closed sets containing $Z$.

The proof I imagined was along these lines \begin{align}\overline{Z} &= \displaystyle\bigcap_{C\supseteq Z,\\C \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n \text{ closed}} C \\& = \displaystyle\bigcap_{\mathfrak{a} \subseteq k[x_1, \ldots, x_n],\\\mathfrak{a} \text{ vanishes on } Z} V(\mathfrak{a}) \\ &= V\left(\sum_{\mathfrak{a} \text{ vanishes on } Z} \mathfrak{a}\right) \\&\ldots?\\ &= V\left(\bigcap_{\mathfrak{m} \text{ vanishes on } Z,\\\mathfrak{m} \text{ maximal}} \right) \\ &= V\left(\bigcap_{x \in Z} \mathfrak{m}_x\right) \\&= V(I(X))  \end{align}

Have I messed this up anywhere? If not, what are the missing steps?

Comment: @Shaun why are you bumping so many old posts lately?

Comment: I'm just making edits where edits are due, @KReiser. I'm also investing a lot of time into algebraic geometry and linear algebraic groups lately, for my formal studies, so I encounter older post with the more basic stuff in. Does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, and there is nothing to add.

Indeed, if $f$ vanishes on $Z$, then by definition $f \in \mathfrak m_x$ for all $x \in Z$. 
Conversely, if $f \in \bigcap_{x \in Z} \mathfrak m_x$, then $\mathfrak a := (f)$ by definition vanishes on $Z$.

This shows that $$ \bigcap_{x \in Z} \mathfrak m_x = \sum_{\mathfrak a \text{ vanishes on } Z} \mathfrak a$$

Comment: Sorry if this is a somewhat obtuse question, but given that correspondence, how do you go from an *intersection* of ideals to a *sum* of ideals?

Comment: No problem ! Recall that $\Sigma \mathfrak a_i$ is the finite linear combinaisons of elements $f_i \in \mathfrak a_i$.
If $f \in \cap \mathfrak m_x$, that means that $\forall x \in Z, f(x) = 0$. In particular, $f$ vanishes on $Z$, so the ideal generated by $f$ vanishes on $f$, in particular $f \in \Sigma_{\mathfrak a \text{ vanishes on Z}} \mathfrak a$. Is this clear ?

Comment: Yes. Intuitively, can I think of the LHS as forming an ideal by cutting it out of very large ideals, and the RHS as building it directly as a $k$-vector space?

Comment: Yes ! (But the RHS is also an ideal as sums of ideals is still an ideal).